# When drawing a gadget Is there a default setting that limits record number?

Tags: cassandra, wso2, dashboard, wso2-das

I'm using wso2 das server and apache cassandra as an external datasource in order to store received events.

When i try to visualize my data (say create a Bar gadget) i dont see all the data i stored in cassandra. I'm wondering if there is a limit on the records DAS fetchs from cassandra ? If so, can i change that default setting ?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers.
Wajdi

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on the maximum number of records fetched per query. The default value is `5000` but you can change it by using the configuration file given below.

```
<DAS_HOME>/repository/conf/datasources/analytics-datasources.xml
```

Inside the `<queryOptions>` XML tag please find the             `<fetchSize>` and update it.

If you need further help regarding this issue please let me know.

Thanks,

Upul

Comment: Thanks for you answer Upul, I already tried setting `<fetchSize>10000000</fetchSize>` with no effect. In fact, i have around 8 million records in a 3 nodes cassandra cluster. what i'm getting back is a tiny portion. FYI, I can explore all my data when i log into carbon UI and use Data Explorer menu.

Comment: here is a TRACE log, @Upul see **LIMIT 5000** and **psize=10000000** a  `[2016-05-10 14:59:01,077] :

TRACE {com.datastax.driver.core.Connection} -  Connection[/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, inFlight=1, closed=false] writing request QUERY SELECT id, timestamp FROM ARS.TS WHERE tenantId = ? AND tableName = ? AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp < ? LIMIT 5000([cl=ONE, vals=[java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4], java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4], java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=11 cap=11], java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=11 cap=11]], skip=false, psize=10000000, state=null, serialCl=SERIAL])`